# SQL Sub_query and joint

Tags: sql, mysql

**Use a sub-query to determine the Community Area Name with most number of crimes?**

i have been trying to solve this Question for few days and I'm having a complete block

would any of you please help me!!

```sql
select community_area_name, community_area_number 
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
where community_area_number in (select community_area_number 
                                from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA 
                                where community_area_number = '25');
```

```sql
select community_area_number, community_area_name 
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
where community_area_number in (select community_area_number 
                                from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA);
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: try exists  select community_area_number, community_area_name 
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS a
where exists(select '' from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA b where a.community_area_number =b.community_area_number )

Comment: in a class that has a similar question and if we have the same information wouldn't your issue be that you are trying to pull information from the CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS table and not the CENSUS_DATA table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want something like this:

```
select cps.community_area_number, cps.community_area_name 
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS cps
where cps.community_area_number = (select ccd.community_area_number 
                                   from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA ccd
                                   order by ccd.num_crimes desc 
                                   limit 1
                                  ) ccd;
```

I have no idea how the number of crimes is determined, so I made up a column.

Note that if there are ties, this returns an arbitrary area.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can try something like this:

```
%%sql 
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER AS MOST_CRIMES FROM CENSUS_DATA
WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IN (SELECT COUNT(COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) FROM CRIME_DATA GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    %%sql select community_area_name 
    from CENSUS_DATA 
    where community_area_number = (select A.community_area_number from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA as A 
    GROUP BY A.community_area_number 
    ORDER BY COUNT (A.community_area_number) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME FROM ChicagoCensusData WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IN (SELECT TOP 2 COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER FROM ChicagoCrimeData GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```

I used top 2 cause de first one with most crimes have no community_area_number

Answer (score 0):

```
result = %sql SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, \
    COUNT(*) AS COUNTING_CRIMES FROM CRIME_DATA \
    GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER ORDER BY COUNTING_CRIMES DESC LIMIT 1
result = result[0][0]

comunity_area_name = %sql SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME \
    FROM CENSUS_DATA WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER =:result
comunity_area_name
OUTPUT: Austin
```

Hello guys, I also had the same question (Hands-on Lab: Problem 10), you could try this code. It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT community_area_name FROM CensusData
WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = (SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER FROM CrimeData 
    GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
    ORDER BY COUNT(COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) DESC
    LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1;
```